# How should I solve this kinda side-effect (redux saga)

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I just ran into a little rabbit hole, and got no idea how to solve this 'nicely'.

What I want:

- I want to dispatch and ACTION,
- I want to change the filter's reducer state according to it.
- I want to grab the dispatched ACTION from a SAGA.
- I want to select an UP-TO-DATE state from the saga. (here is the
  rabbit hole)

So how could I say the saga to wait until the reducer changes, so I it's can select the up-to-date state. (of course I COULD handle the changes in both the reducer, and the saga, but is there a different way, where I handle the change just once?)

```
    // filters/actions.js
    const changeFilterOption = (option, value) => ({
        type: CHANGE_FILTER_OPTION,
        payload: {
            option,
            value
        }
    })

    // filters/reducer.js
    reducer(state=initState, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
        //...
        case CHANGE_FILTER_OPTION: 
            return changedFilterOptions...
        //...
        }
    }

    // listing/saga.js
    saga(takeLatest(CHANGE_FILTER_OPTION, doSomeAPICallWithTheNewData))

    function* doSomeAPICallWithTheNewData() {
        //at this point the reducer might not changed yet,
        //of course I can grab the payload and handle the changes in the saga as well.

        //selectedOptions might not be updated...
        const options = yield select(selectFilterOptions)
        yield call(api.doSomeAPICall, option)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sagas will receive the action after the reducer had updated the store. So you are safe to assume that the data you select from the store is up-to-date.

However, the data "maybe" stale in rare cases where any middleware in the flow before the sagaMiddleware does not synchronously call `next(action)`.

**References**

Read the blockquote in the official docs:
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#selectselector-args

A GitHub comment from the author:
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/148#issuecomment-187898044

Source code:
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/middleware.js#L44

Comment: Ahhh, I totally missed this. I thought I receive the action before it's hit the reducer. Thanks for making me realise this :)